# Slow network transfer on gigabit between Win7 and Ubuntu Samba (26 MB/s)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, vmware-esxi, samba, gigabit-ethernet

I have slow network transfer speed (26 MB/s). The beginning of the transfer started at 120 MB/s and dropped down every second.

I am transferring a 350 GB file from an E-Sata (7200rpm) drive mounted on Windows 7 to a Ubuntu Samba share (on esxi). The samba share is mapped to a drive letter on Win 7 by IP address.

ethtool eth0 shows:

> Settings for eth0:
>   Supported ports: TP
>   Supported link modes: 10/100 half/full, 1000/full
>   Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
>   Advertised pause frame use: No
>   Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
>   Speed: 1000MB/s
>   Duplex: Full
>   Port: Twisted Pair
>   PHYAD: 0
>   Transceiver: internal
>   Auto-negotiation: on
>   MDI-X: Unknown
>   Supports Wake-on: d
>   Wake-on: d
>   Current Message level: 7
>   link detected: yes

Comment: If you checked the speed of both disks, and checked the raw network speed with `iperf` or similar, then make sure you connect with SMB2 or SMB3, not SMB1 which is slower. And/or show us the output of `testparm -s`  and `smbd --version` on your Samba server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to test disk for wtite speed with dd in linux. and then check your network with iperf. and you ll know where is a bottle neck.

Answer (score 3):

The hard drive almost certainly only supports ~26MBps. Even the latest round of SATA drives can barely pull double that number (under ideal conditions).

That beginning speed of 120MBps isn't even really possible; 1000Mb / 8 * 80% = ~100MBps (realistic max). Windows caching is playing with the numbers, hence the high initial speed and after a while the number settles to the sustainable throughput.

Comment: Modern SATA disks can give linear sustainable speeds up to 100MB/s and more. 200MB/s is not uncommon with disks with large data densities.

Comment: Man it was 2011 when the guy was replying.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone to know: on Ubuntu 20.04.1 and ARM64 (where this does comply with standard x64 system) with Samba I had transfer both directions at about 115 MB/s, which means that with Gigabit Ethernet you can achieve much higher speeds than mentioned in the question - using SSD drives, memory or data produced from `/dev/zero`.

Problem can be:

1. Ethernet working on one side (source/target) at 100 Mb/s
2. Not proper file system (in my case NTFS was not giving more than 30 MB/s)
3. HDD which for SATA gives max at around 130 MB/s